# Generate a series of tensors using RNN

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am building a rnn and I use tf.nn.dynamic_rnn to yield the output and state.
The code is as follows (tf version 1.3):

```
import tensorflow as tf    
def lstm_cell():
        return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(128), output_keep_prob=0.7)

cell= tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(3)])

initial_state= cell.zero_state(1, tf.float32)

layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,1,36])

outputs, state=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=layer, initial_state=initial_state)
```

Since the input tensor is always of batch size =1, the initial_state and state also have a batch size 1.
layer is an input of batch_size=1 as well, and for each cell there are 36 nodes(size of the embedded sequence). Each layer has lstm_size 128.

The problem comes when I loop the rnn cell.

```
rnn_outputs_sequence=outputs
for i in range(1, num_pics, 1):
    outputs, state=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=outputs, initial_state=state)
    rnn_outputs_sequence=tf.concat((rnn_outputs_sequence, outputs),axis=1)
```

rnn_outputs_sequence is expected to have shape [1, num_pics, 36].However, this triggers an error:

```
Trying to share variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape (256, 512) and found shape (164, 512).
```

I cannot figure out this shape [164, 512].
Can anyone help me with this out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
def lstm_cell():
    return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(128), output_keep_prob=0.7)

cell= tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(2)])

initial_state= cell.zero_state(1, tf.float32)

layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,1,36])

outputs, state=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=layer, initial_state=initial_state)

outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, shape=[1, -1])
outputs = tf.layers.dense(outputs, 36,\
                                 kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, shape=[1, 1, -1])
rnn_outputs_sequence=outputs
print(outputs)
for i in range(1, 16, 1):
    outputs, state=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=outputs, initial_state=state)
    outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, shape=[1, -1])
    outputs = tf.layers.dense(outputs, 36,\
                                 kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
    outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, shape=[1, 1, -1])
    print(outputs)
    rnn_outputs_sequence=tf.concat((rnn_outputs_sequence, outputs),axis=1)
print(rnn_outputs_sequence)
```